# Best way to rate limit clientside api in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

I've ran into an issue which i'm struggling to decide the best way to solve. Perhaps my software articheture needs to change?

I have a cron job which hits my website method every 10 seconds and then on my website the method then makes an API call each time to an API however the API is rate limited x amount in a minute and y amount a day

Currently i'm exceeding the API limits and need to control this in the website method somehow. I've thought storing in a file perhaps but seems hacky similary to a database as I don't currently use one for this project.

I've tried this package: https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/RateLimiter but alas it doesn't work in my scenario and I think it would work if I did one request with a loop as provided in his examples. I noticed he had a persistent timer(PersistentCountByIntervalAwaitableConstraint) but he has no documentation or examples for it(I emailed him incase). I've done a lot of googling around and can't find any examples of this only server rate limiting which is the other way around server limiting client and not client limiting requests to server

How can I solve my issue **without** changing the cronjobs? What does everyone think the best solution to this is?

Comment: So you want to rate-limit *yourself*, and not incoming requests?  Changing the cronjob so it runs less often seems like the obvious solution.

Comment: You could cache the results if possible. For example, the same request might be called every minute but the data only changes every hour. If you want to limit, you'll need to store a count somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't want to change the clients generating the load, there is no choice but to implement rate limiting on the server.

Since an ASP.NET application can be restarted at any time, the state used for that rate-limiting must be persisted somewhere. You can choose any data store you like for that.

In this case you have two limits: One per minute and one per day. If you simply apply two separate rate limiters you will end up with the daily limit being exceeded fairly quickly. After that, there will be no further access for the rest of the day. Likely, this is undesirable.

It seems better to only apply the daily limit because it is more restrictive. A simple solution would be to calculate how far apart requests must be to meet the daily limit. Then, you store the date of the last request. Any new incoming request is immediately failed if not enough time has passed.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Currenty limited by 5 per minute and 500 per day total. So what you're suggesting is diving the 500 per the 24 hours? Then working with the 5 per minute or so? Struggling to work out a good solution to this. Thinking i'll have to pivot to a database to record these api requests

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You can record the date of the latest request. So one table, one column, one row. Or, just log all requests.

Comment: if I had one row though I woudn't know if i'm exceeding the 500 total

Comment: If you execute only one request every 86400/500 seconds you would know that the total is being observed. And the requests would be spread evenly over the day.